# MongoDB: Slice with percentage

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to have `slice()` return a *percentage* of the returned results? Like, not the first 20, but given the total number of results, return the 20% of them.

Comment: @pistacchio, can you post some example of your document?

Comment: 20% of the documents from a query? Not unless you know how many would have been returned anyway. What do you mean by `slice()` -- it's for arrays.

Comment: you can do it with MapRedice, if _really_ want to do it inside MongoDB, but it is not fast/simple.

Answer (score 1):

No, slice can only be used for the number of array elements at the moment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/slice/